# .pbtxt file for ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

Sorry, I am new to making models with Tensorflow 2.0.

I am trying to train a model using the pre-trained model: ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320 from the Tensorflow 2.0 Object Detection Zoo. I am following a tutorial that uses the .pbtxt file for the model and I am not sure how I can get it as the model only has a .pb file.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md
Here is the link. I am planning on using the SSD MobileNet v2 320x320 for my model.

Basically my question is: how do I get a .pbtxt file to refer to in `pipeline.config` file, or is there something else I can put for the `label_map_path`?

train_input_reader {

label_map_path: "PATH"

tf_record_input_reader {

input_path: "PATH"

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the "pbtxt" file based on what you are trying to train the object-detection model for.
The format for pbtxt file is:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'class name 1'
}

item {
    id: 2
    name: 'class name 2'
}
```

For example, if you are training the object detection model to detect cats and dogs.
Your label_map.pbtxt file would look like.

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'cat'
}

item {
    id: 2
    name: 'dog'
}
```

Note: This name should exactly match the name you give to the category while labelling your image. ie labelling using labelImg software.

For complete guide on using Tensorflow object detection API.
See [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html)

After creating the label_map.pbtxt file you just have to specify the path of the file in your pipeline.pbtxt.

```
train_input_reader {

label_map_path: "PATH_TO_LABEL_MAP_FOLDER/label_map.pbtxt"

tf_record_input_reader {

input_path: "PATH"

}

}
```

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote if the solution worked.

Comment: Thanks, Aniket! I upvotes and marked it as a solution.